# Проверка на тип приложения

Tags: c++, winapi

Как можно проверить консольное ли приложение или оконное? Может в `winapi` есть какое-то описание процесса, его свойств?

Comment: Не уверен, но думаю, что все программы в каком-то роде консольные, т.е. для них доступны ввод вывод в консоль. Просто у некотрых программ консоль скрывается и остается только окошко с приложением. Знаю, что в студии после указания этих флагов косольное окошко скрывается: `/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`. Возможно вас стоит копать куда-то в эту сторону.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308408/how-to-detect-console-or-windows-application

Comment: Собственно, в ассоциированном вопросе уже ответили, добавить нечего, там ссылаются на подробный пример - [PEDUMP.C](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx#code-snippet-3). Вам надо только прочитать значение поля Subsystem. Если консоль, то тут будет `WINDOWS_CUI`.

Comment: Какое именно приложение вам надо проверить: "самого себя",  посторонний процесс или посторонний `.exe` файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете майкрософтовский SDK, то начиная с версии 10 для проверки "самого себя" у вас есть [недокументированная или полу-документированная] возможность сделать

```
#include <process.h>

...
_crt_app_type type = _query_app_type();
```

с возвращаемыми значениями `_crt_console_app` и `_crt_gui_app`.

Аналогичные возможности есть и в более ранних версиях SDK, но интерфейс варьируется.

Answer (score 3):

В текущем процессе проверить, является ли приложение консольным, можно так:

```
#include <Dbghelp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp")
extern "C" const IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

...

bool isConsole(){
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt = ImageNtHeader((void*)&__ImageBase);
    return nt->OptionalHeader.Subsystem == IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо - то, что нужно!